Power Query Merge producing many additional rows
In Power Query, I am trying to Merge MB51 Table (exported to .xlsx from SAP) and YS23 on the Sales Document Column. There are many duplicates of each Sales Document Number in each table.  This Merge should enable me to match the Bill of Material of each assembled product.  There are 72432 rows in MB51 and 332529 rows in YS23.  There are 58163 rows in YS23 that match MB51 Sales Document Numbers.
There are 72432 rows in MB51 and 332529 rows in YS23.  There are 58163 rows in YS23 that match MB51 Sales Document Numbers.
I select the Merge as follows:
Merge Screenshot
I then expand the table with the Material and Material Description fields so I will be able to filter on the Assembled Product Material Codes.  The Merge produces 404 425 rows.
Can somebody please assist?

If the answer posted does not solve your problem, please edit your question to provide a sample data table which reproduces your problem as text which can be copy/pasted perhaps using this Markdown Tables Generator. See How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and consider Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

If there are multiple rows per matched merge row, then these are carried over and will duplicate when expanded.
You will need to clean up on of the tables to remove the duplicates and excessive columns. For example, Reference query YS23 to create a new query. Then remove all the unnecessary columns (ie keep Sales Document, Material, and Material Description). Then remove duplicates on Sales Document. Final merge and expand using this new query.
The above will ensure there is only one row per matched in the Merge so that when you expand you will shouldn't get an increase of rows.

Thank you so much! this helped so much and worked!
